# Interpretation of Array notation for Permutations

Tags: group-theory, permutations, notation

EDIT: The big picture here is that I want to be able to reason about permutations in concrete terms. Most of the examples I see show permutations in either 2-row or cycle notation, but rarely refer back to the resulting configuration from applying them. In order to try to understand this better, I tried playing around with sequences of letters. It seemed natural to adapt the 2-row notation to refer instead to actual elements in a sequence, as in  $$\begin{pmatrix}\boldsymbol{A} & B & C\\\ \boldsymbol{2} & 1 & 3\end{pmatrix}$$. I realise this may have caused more problems than it solved.

It appears that a column in array notation for permutations expresses two different facts.

e.g.

$$\begin{pmatrix}\boldsymbol{A} & B & C\\\ \boldsymbol{2} & 1 & 3\end{pmatrix}$$

- The element which was in position 1 in the original goes to position 2 in the image
- The element in position 1 of the image is the element which came from position 2 in the original

I'm having trouble understanding this. Are the two facts somehow equivalent, like deriving facts about multiplication from facts about division? They seem somewhat unrelated to me, but that is maybe because I'm having trouble "getting my map oriented" when it comes to permutations.

Also, is there a term for the resulting configuration from applying a permutation? I.e. for the given example, the original sequence of $A, B, C$ would become $B, A, C$. How do we refer to $B, A, C$? Is it something like "the image of the original configuration under the permutation?"

Should this be described in terms of function composition? Maybe

$\left( \begin{array}{cc}
A & B & C \\
1 & 2 & 3
\end{array} \right)
%
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
A & B & C \\
2 & 1 & 3
\end{array} \right)
=
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
A & B & C \\
2 & 1 & 3
\end{array} \right)$

(I get that this is horribly wrong. I include it to illustrate the depth of my confusion. It doesn't help that I'm not sure if 2-row notation ever corresponds to a configuration rather than an action, and if so under what conditions.)

It seems the 2-row notation $$\begin{pmatrix}\boldsymbol{A} & B & C\\\ \boldsymbol{2} & 1 & 3\end{pmatrix}$$ actually contains the original configuration within the first row.

It's surprising to me how such an apparently simple notation can be so slippery. Can anyone please help me to clarify my understanding?

Comment: I have seen the permutation notation $(123)$, and I have seen the permutation notation $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&2&3\\2&3&1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$, but I have not seen $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}A&B&C\\2&3&1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$. How does that work?

Comment: It is the result of me experimenting in order to help myself to understand permutations. I want to be able to work with concrete examples, such as sequences of letters. It could be that I "broke" Maths in my attempt ;)

Comment: If you're going to use letters instead of numbers, don't stop halfway! Let $\sigma=\pmatrix{A&B&C\cr B&C&A\cr}$; then $\sigma$ is the permutation given by $\sigma(A)=B$, $\sigma(B)=C$, $\sigma(C)=A$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson My current task is writing a computer program that takes a list of elements, which can be of any type, and a permutation in the form of a list of integers, and returns the actual new configuration, as opposed to some new permutation (my confusion between "configuration" and "permutation" is driving me nuts!) So in this instance, it makes sense to have characters for the list of elements and integers for the contents of the permutation, no?

Comment: It looks like you are considering the bijections from $\{A,B,C\}$ to $\{1,2,3\}$. If so, the blocking point that I see is that you can't compose any two of them, so no chance I guess to give any structure to the set of such maps. To do that, domain and codomain of the bijections must coincide.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer that might help, offering a different notation.

I think I can see the two different ways you are thinking of a permutation: *functions* vs *rearrangments*. One way to think of permutations is a function, eg in the permutation below $\sigma(1) = 3, \sigma(2) = 4$, etc. In this example 1 changes to 3.

Another way to think about it is rearranging objects in front of you, eg if your favourite sports team where 1st last season, and are now third. In this example your favourite sports team doesn't change (it's still Mathletico Madrid, say), but *it's position changes*.

What I *think* you are trying to capture in your ABC123 notation is the second one, ie moving away from a function to a rearrangment. THere is something fixed changing position.

[image]

Here's a possible improvement on the ABC123 notation, try drawing coloured lines. Here you can see the red line (which is permenant), moving from 1st to 3rd.

[image]

You can also stack permutations vertically to get composition, and see where the red line ends up going under multiple permutations. Here's the function composed with it's inverse.

[image]

Hope this gives you some way of thinking about it that's clearer. (pictures taken from : https://groupsmadesimple.wordpress.com/2020/05/27/parity-of-permutations-by-pictures/ )

Comment: Thanks for the input. The further down this rabbit hole I go, the less things make sense, at the moment. I've just read this: https://gowers.wordpress.com/2011/10/16/permutations/#comment-430138  (and the comments at the end) and it seems that my confusion is not so rare. There is also the active/passive distinction, https://www.tau.ac.il/~tsirel/dump/Static/knowino.org/wiki/Permutation_group.html which I think is just another way of framing the same distinction discussed in the first article.

Comment: The permutations of meaning are somewhat overwhelming. My main interest here is using permutations to solve physical puzzles (15-puzzle, Rubiks etc.), so the rearrangement idea is probably most helpful, if I can get a handle on how to interpret the standard notations as configurations of these puzzles.

Comment: oh I got into a right pickle with the 15 puzzle and cycle notation, as you've got the numbering of the tiles, and the numbering of the placeholders for the tiles, and you need to keep really clear which is when you write (12). Indexing the tile labels by letters could be a great idea here @RobinAndrews ! Good luck!

Comment: So does (1 2) mean swap the tiles labelled 1 and 2 or the tiles in positions 1 and 2?

Comment: It's positions 1 and 2. THe difficulty, which you've quite rightly identified, is that you can't use cycle notation to easily keep track of where each object is mapped (and if anyone does know a way, tell me too!). Assuming tiles start in the right positions, then (12) swaps tiles 1 and 2, but for (123)(12), the (12) is swapping tiles 1 and 3. And after something like (1245)(23)(15 16)(3 16)(12), it's a real pen and paper exercise to work out *what* the (12) is actually changing, relative to the tile labels.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that this is what you look for, but you can label the elements of *any* finite set $A$ as $A=\{a_1,\dots,a_n\}$; then, any permutation $\sigma\in S_n$ induces a rearrangement of the elements of $A$ by means of the bijection *on $A$* defined by $a_i\mapsto a_{\sigma(i)}$.

For example, call $a_1:=A, a_2:=B, a_3:=C$; then, the permutation $(123)$ (cycle notation) induces the rearrangement $(A,B,C)\mapsto (B,C,A)$.